# SQL Query: Finding Overdue Start Date and Overdue Amount from a table

Tags: sql, zoho

I have a table as follows, in which there is a 'ODType' column, This column states that a transaction is Due (D) or Collection-ed (C) amount. From this i need to find out overdue start date and overdue amount for each loan.

```
LoanID  OverDueDate TotalAmount ODType
12345   01/10/17    1000        D
12345   01/11/17    500         C
12345   03/12/17    1000        D 
12346   01/10/17    1500        D
12346   01/11/17    500         C
12346   03/12/17    1000        C
12346   01/01/18    2000        D
12346   01/02/18    1000        C
```

Examples Scenarios:

- if we take LoanID 12345, The Overdue start date is: 01/10/2017 and
  overdue Amount is: 1500
- if we take LoanID 12346, The Overdue start date is:
  01/01/2018 and overdue Amount is: 1000

I am able to get the overdue amounts for each loanId, but not sure how to get the Overdue start date. i did it with the following query:

```
SELECT t.LoanID, (t."DemandAmount" -t."CollectionAmount") Overdue 
FROM (SELECT
         LoanID,
         MAX(CASE
                 WHEN ODType  = 'D' THEN ("TotalAmount")
             END) AS DemandAmount,
         MAX(CASE
                 WHEN (ODType  = 'C') THEN ("TotalAmount")
             END) AS CollectionAmount
FROM  TXN_OverdueCollection GROUP BY  LoanID ) t
```

How to find out the overdue start date, what is the additional criteria i need to add to get it apart from the overdue amount. Or do i need to change the query completely to get both Overdue start date and overdue amounts.

**UPDATE:** 
*Overdue Amount and Overdue start date calculation information as follows:*

- The Overdue amount comes by SUM Of Dues(D) minus SUM Of Collections (C).
- Suppose if we take the LoanID 12345, Sum of D (Dues) is 2000 and the
  C (Collection) is 500 only so 2000 - 500 = 1500 is the due and since
  it does not fulfill the 01/10/2017 full payment, the overdue start
  date is 01/10/2017 only.
- Suppose if we take the LoanID 12346, Sum of D(Dues) is 3500 and the C
  (Collection) is 2500, So the overdue amount is 3500 - 2500 = 1000 and
  overdue start date is 01/01/18, as it did not fulfill that dates due
  yet.

**Note**:
This needs to be achived with simple JOIN OR LEFT OR RIGHT or Inner JOIN queries. Does not work with Partition, LAG, OVER and row_Number keywords which means these built in functions are not available to write the query.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: `if we take LoanID 12345, The Overdue start date is: 01/10/2017 and overdue Amount is: 1500` - How do you calculate the 1500? You have 3 records for `12345` and none of them are 1500. It looks even more complex for `12346`.

Comment: @Shawn, Thank you for your response, I have given that explanation under the **UPDATE**. Please go through it.

Comment: So the overdue time is essentially the time of the next `D` when `D - C = 0`?

Comment: Why does `C` have an overdue date? Is `OverDueDate` really a transaction date?

Comment: @Shawn, If D - C = 0 then no Overdue. and yes when the record being placed with D then the Overdue starts but based on the collections after that it will change. C has a date as it is the amount collected date. naming convention of the column, Please ignore. Suppose an amount has to be received by a date, if that is not received the record will be placed with D for that Date, but any day whatever the amount is received that will be placed with C with that amount and respective date. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: And what type of SQL?

Comment: @Shawn, Just normal SQL statements.

Comment: What type of SQL server? Microsoft, Oracle, MySQL, Postgre, something else?

Comment: Its not belongs to the list you mentioned, It works with simple sql queries. Its called "Zoho Reports"

Answer (score 0):

This is Microsoft T-SQL syntax, and depending on your server language, it will likely be different. I use MS-SQL's `LAG()` function, which was introduced in MS SQL 2012. All of the concepts *should* be convertible to whatever flavor of SQL you are using.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/117f8/2)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t ( LoanID int, OverDueDate date, TotalAmount decimal(10,2), ODType varchar(1));
INSERT INTO t ( LoanID, OverDueDate, TotalAmount, ODType )
VALUES 
    (12345, '01/10/17', 1000, 'D')
  , (12345, '01/11/17',  500, 'C')
  , (12346, '02/10/17', 1500, 'D')
  , (12346, '03/12/17', 1000, 'C') /* Paid off. But more loans. */
  , (12346, '01/02/18', 1000, 'C') 
  , (12345, '03/12/17', 1000, 'D') /* Additional deposit. Maintains original overdue date */
  , (12346, '02/11/17',  500, 'C')
  , (12346, '01/01/18', 2000, 'D')
  , (12347, '10/01/17', 1000, 'D')
  , (12347, '11/01/17', 1001, 'C') /* Overpaid */
  , (12348, '11/11/17', 1000, 'D')
  , (12348, '12/11/17', 1000, 'C') /* Paid off */
;
```

I added a couple of extra rows to the data to demonstrate some variations, like over-payment or paying off a loan. I also changed up the order of some of the dates to show how the `ORDER BY` in the `OVER()` window function will correct for out-of-order data.

**Query**: ***NOTE:*** *I commented the SQL to explain some of what I did.*

```
; WITH cte1 AS ( /* Created CTE because use this query in main and sub query. */
  SELECT s1.LoanID
      , s1.OverDueDate
      , s1.TotalAmount
      , s1.ODType
      , s1.runningTotal
      , CASE 
          WHEN ( 
            COALESCE ( /* COALESCE() will handle NULL dates. */
              LAG(s1.runningTotal) /* LAG() is SQL2012.  */
              OVER ( PARTITION BY s1.LoanID ORDER BY s1.LoanID, s1.OverDueDate )
              , 0 ) <= 0 
                /* This resets the OverDueDate. "<=0" will reset date for overpays. */
          ) THEN s1.OverDueDate 
          ELSE NULL 
        END AS od
      , s1.rn
  FROM (
      SELECT t.LoanID
        , t.OverDueDate
        , t.TotalAmount
        , t.ODType
        , SUM( CASE 
                  WHEN t.ODType = 'D' THEN t.TotalAmount 
                  WHEN t.ODType = 'C' THEN t.TotalAmount*-1 
                  ELSE 0 
                END ) 
          OVER (
               PARTITION BY LoanID 
               ORDER BY OverDueDate
          ) AS runningTotal
            /* We need to be able to calculate + (D) and - (C) to get a running total. */
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t.LoanID ORDER BY t.OverDueDate DESC ) AS rn
            /* ROW_NUMBER() helps us find the most recent record for the LoanID. */
      FROM t
    ) s1
)
SELECT b.LoanID
  , b.TotalAmount
  , b.ODType
  , b.runningTotal
  , CASE 
      WHEN b.od IS NOT NULL THEN b.od
      WHEN b.runningTotal <= 0 THEN NULL /* If they don't owe, they aren't overdue. */
      ELSE (  SELECT max(s1.od)
              FROM cte1 s1
              WHERE b.LoanID = s1.LoanID
                AND s1.OverDueDate <= b.OverDueDate
            ) 
      END AS runningOverDue /* Calculate the running overdue date. */
FROM cte1 b
WHERE b.rn=1 /* rn=1 gets the most recent record for each LoanID. */
  AND b.runningTotal <> 0 /* This will exclude anyone who doesn't currently 
               owe money but did. Change to >0 to include only overdues. */
ORDER BY b.LoanID, b.OverDueDate
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/117f8/2/0)**:

```
| LoanID | overduedate | TotalAmount | ODType | runningTotal | runningOverDue |
|--------|-------------|-------------|--------|--------------|----------------|
|  12345 |  2017-03-12 |        1000 |      D |         1500 |     2017-01-10 |
|  12346 |  2018-01-02 |        1000 |      C |         1000 |     2018-01-01 |
|  12347 |  2017-11-01 |        1001 |      C |           -1 |         (null) |
```

Comment: Yuck. The execution plan is ugly. If it runs over a lot of rows or is run regularly, I'm sure it can be torn down and optimized.

Comment: Thank you for the solution but it does not work for me, as LAG, OVER , PARTITION BY Keywords are not available for my SQL Queries, It is limited to write the queries. It allows LEFT, RIGHT, INNER JOINs, Group by and Order by only.

Comment: As far as I could tell, Zoho doesn't use its own database. It uses one you've set up. With such simple SQL structures available, I'm not sure you can get at what you're trying to get at. You may need to go all the way back to your database and make a view. Do you know what type of database Zoho is sitting on?